# Android RecycleView No Adapter Attached, Skipping Layout

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, crud

I have search an error about no adapter attached. There is so many duplicated question about it and have different answer, and nothing fix my error.

So, I working on CRUD Apps with Retrofit. I can insert data to database through application but when i tried to view data my RecyclerView didn't appear.

Logcat Message :

```
RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

And this my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btIns;
ApiInterface mApiInterface;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public static MainActivity ma;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btIns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btIns);
    btIns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, InsertActivity.class));
        }
    });
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mApiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    ma=this;
    refresh();
}

public void refresh() {
    Call<GetKontak> kontakCall = mApiInterface.getKontak();
    kontakCall.enqueue(new Callback<GetKontak>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetKontak> call, Response<GetKontak>
                response) {
            List<Kontak> KontakList = response.body().getListDataKontak();
            Log.d("Retrofit Get", "Jumlah data Kontak: " +
                    String.valueOf(KontakList.size()));
            mAdapter = new KontakAdapter(KontakList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetKontak> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Retrofit Get", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrofit callbacks are executed in a background thread, where you can't call `setAdapter`. Create the adapter and set it in the main thread, by calling `mRecyclerView.post(runnable)`, with runnable containing the code you need to execute on the main thread.

Comment: Would you explain how to do it in my code? I'm really new in this and still didn't know what i have to do.

Comment: Do this: `Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { mAdapter = new KontakAdapter(KontakList); mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); }; mRecyclerView.post(runnable);`